# How to solve the problem of Devtools in django?

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

Whenever I load the page, it gives me the following error in command-line interface and error in chrome console also. Although it is loading in chrome, page is not loading in firefox. How to deal with this problem? How to make it work in every browser instead of just chrome?

```
[14/Feb/2020 07:06:29] "GET /static/home/js/popper.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1802
[14/Feb/2020 07:06:29] "GET /static/home/js/bootstrap.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1811
```

**Image to see the error in console**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LryCT.png]

Comment: Try clearing cache once and then recheck your addresses for static files, almost all your .js files are invalid, you might consider re-downloading those.

Comment: Is there any other way. There is bunch of code I wrote there. How could I download the template again?

Comment: It shows that your js files for bootstrap, jquery, and whatever APIs you have used are missing.
I would suggest you to add their CDNs in a single file like base.html and extend all your HTML files from that base.html
You can easily check the documentation for how to extend html templates

Comment: That's not the case. Sorry but you misunderstood.

Comment: Oh, My bad, sorry. What was the issue by the way?

Comment: I am now using another template.